# Golang Docker Compose

Tags: docker, go, docker-compose

I am totally confused here.
I have 3 folders. 2 of which have a docker file and the third has a docker-compose as follow

```
Project1
|-- Dockerfile
|--go.mod
|--main.go

Project2
|-- Dockerfile
|--go.mod
|--main.go

Project3
|-- docker.compose
```

I am using the docker compose to build all the required projects that I need now and others in the future.

The docker file are structured as:

```
FROM golang:alpine

# Add Maintainer info

# Install git.
# Git is required for fetching the dependencies.
RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache git && apk add --no-cache bash && apk add build-base

# Setup folders
RUN mkdir /app

WORKDIR /app

# Copy the source from the current directory to the working Directory inside the container
COPY . .
#COPY .env .

# Download all the dependencies

RUN go get -d -v ./...

# Install the package
RUN go install -v ./...

#Setup hot-reload for dev stage
RUN go get github.com/githubnemo/CompileDaemon
RUN go install -mod=mod github.com/githubnemo/CompileDaemon
RUN go get -v golang.org/x/tools/gopls

EXPOSE 3000
ENTRYPOINT CompileDaemon --build="go build -a -installsuffix cgo -o main ." --command=./main
```

Both Dockerfiles are the same.

while in the docker compose I have this:

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  login:
    container_name: login_container
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=${DB_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
      - POSTGRES_DB=${DB_NAME}
      - DATABASE_HOST=${DB_HOST}
      - DATABASE_PORT=${DB_PORT}
      - TEST_POSTGRES_USER=${TEST_DB_USER}
      - TEST_POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${TEST_DB_PASSWORD}
      - TEST_POSTGRES_DB=${TEST_DB_NAME}
      - TEST_DATABASE_HOST=${TEST_DB_HOST}
      - TEST_DATABASE_PORT=${TEST_DB_PORT}
    tty: true
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: ../project1/dockerfile
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    restart: on-failure
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    depends_on:
      - postgresdb
    networks:
      - learning
  posts:
    container_name: post_container
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=${DB_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
      - POSTGRES_DB=${DB_NAME}
      - DATABASE_HOST=${DB_HOST}
      - DATABASE_PORT=${DB_PORT}
      - TEST_POSTGRES_USER=${TEST_DB_USER}
      - TEST_POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${TEST_DB_PASSWORD}
      - TEST_POSTGRES_DB=${TEST_DB_NAME}
      - TEST_DATABASE_HOST=${TEST_DB_HOST}
      - TEST_DATABASE_PORT=${TEST_DB_PORT}
    tty: true
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: ../project2/dockerfile
    ports:
      - 3005:3000
    restart: on-failure
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    depends_on:
      - postgresdb
    networks:
      - learning


  postgresdb:
    image: postgres:latest
    container_name: postgres_container
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=${DB_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
      - POSTGRES_DB=${DB_NAME}
      - DATABASE_HOST=${DB_HOST}
    ports:
      - '1234:5432'
    volumes:
      - ./pg_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      - learning


volumes:
  pg_data:
  pg_data_test:

# Networks to be created to facilitate communication between containers
networks:
  learning:
    driver: bridge
```

when I run the command `docker-compose build` I get this error

```
RUN go get -d -v ./...:                                                                                                                                                                              
#12 0.268 go: go.mod file not found in current directory or any parent directory.                                                                                                                                            
#12 0.268       'go get' is no longer supported outside a module.                                                                                                                                                            
#12 0.268       To build and install a command, use 'go install' with a version,                                                                                                                                             
#12 0.268       like 'go install example.com/cmd@latest'                                                                                                                                                                     
#12 0.268   For more information, see https://golang.org/doc/go-get-install-deprecation
#12 0.268   or run 'go help get' or 'go help install'.
------
```

The go.mod it is present in both folders but I don't understand why exactly is not finding it or how to debug this.

Comment: Set the context to the directory containing Dockerfile

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I tried this before and it did solved the issue with the docker build. But when I run the docker up, I get the exact error in the console. Logging inside the container, I see that the docker instead of copying the source from the project 1/2 folder, it copies the content of project3

Comment: That's what the context directory means. The docker image is built from files under the context dir.

Comment: I do agree with you. But in this scenario. even if I set the context to `../project-1` directory, and login into that container, I have the files from `Project-3` which is docker-compose directory.

Comment: Your `volumes:` are hiding everything that goes into the image, which might be why you're getting confused on which files are where.  I'd recommend deleting those (and also the automatic-rebuild tooling).

Comment: @DavidMaze That was it. totally forgot about the `.:/app` i changed the source in the volume and everything worked as expected. Thank you so much